# Trying to create custom SFDC connector in Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, sfdc

I am trying to create a custom salesforce connector with Azure Logic Apps. Unfortunately when I am trying authorization with Oauth2 I get the error below:

```
error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration
```

Azure Logic apps security tab screenshot
[Logic Apps Security tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap3uB.png)
Salesforce connected App screenshot
[sfdc connected app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vQ8Y.png)

So callback URLs are the same. Am I missing something else?

I show that Logic Apps is sending redirect_url parameter and salesforce is expecting redirect_uri but I am not sure if this could be the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.